# pass nested Model class object as JSON api parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have Model Class which constist varies properties some the property also consist object of another model class.My problem is i want to pass Model class object as JSON api parameter directly.

Please suggest me way.

Ex.

```
#import "locationModel.h"
interface userModel:NSObject

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *uName;

@property (nonatomic,retain) locationModel *mLocation;
// locationModel consist two Properties Lat Lng

@end
```

I want to pass objUserModel to json api as parameters.
Please suggest me way to pass objUserModel as an jsonapiparameters.

Thanks inadvance

Comment: Why don't you try [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper)?

Comment: Kazunori but i dont want to use third party tool.. any other suggestion

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I used this method finally but still it create problem in nested model objects
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithPropertiesOfObject:(id)obj
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    unsigned count;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([obj class], &count);
   
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[i])];
            [dict setObject:[obj valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
    }
    free(properties);
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
}

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `ModelObject` class, and change all your model classes to subclass of this class. Then change the implementation of `dictionaryWithPropertiesOfObject:` to something like this:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithPropertiesOfObject:(id)obj {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    unsigned count;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([obj class], &count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[i])];
        if([obj valueForKey:key]!=nil){
            id targetObject = [obj valueForKey:key];
            if ([targetObject isKindOfClass:[ModelObject class]]){
                [dict setObject:[self dictionaryWithPropertiesOfObject: targetObject]  forKey:key];
            }
            else if ([targetObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
                [dict setObject:[self arrayWithDictionariesForObjectsInArray: (NSArray *)targetObject] forKey:key];
            }
            else {
                [dict setObject:targetObject forKey:key];
            }
        }
    }
    free(properties);
    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
}

- (NSArray *) arrayWithDictionariesForObjectsInArray: (NSArray *) array {
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (id object in array){
        [mutableArray addObject:[self dictionaryWithPropertiesOfObject:object]];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray]; 
}
```

So all the instances of a `ModelObject` are inserted in the dictionary with their dictionary representation.

Comment: still i found one problem i have NSMutableArray <locationModel *> *mLocation but when i try to access it it will crash reason Invalid Type in JSON write (locationModel).. please help me .. @lorenzoliveto